# How to use electron ipc to update text field

Tags: html, node.js, electron

I have been researching my issue and all arrows point to ipcRender / ipcMain to handle DOM events when using electron. But it seems when using ipc, the webpage does the send and the js file does the receiving. I need to do it backwards - and I am not sure this is accurate or possible. So I am looking for some clarification and assistance.

My `main.js` connects to a rate table via ZMQ and polls for position and velocity. I want to in turn, take the received information and send it to my `index.html` and display in text fields. There is zero user interaction in this application. The JS code just runs and updates the values in the HTML front end.
The Data is collected and sent from `pollPos` and `pollVel` functions - where you'll see `ipcMain.send` which YES I know isnt real functionality. I don;t want to need to wait on an event to send because the data from table updates very rapidly.

How do I properly use ipc to display my data into the text fields? Or should I use something else entirely?

main.js

```
let zmq = require("zeromq");
const { stringify } = require("querystring");

// Electron stuff for the POSITION and VELOCITY GUI. 
const electron = require('electron');
const { app, ipcMain, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const { DH_NOT_SUITABLE_GENERATOR } = require("constants");
const { deflate } = require("zlib");

// function for delay 
const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

// creating ZMQ Request
let sock = new zmq.Request();

// Bool for connection to Rate Table. 
let connected = Boolean(false);

// Events for the zmq request.
let events = sock.events;

// Global instance of guiWindow. 
var guiWindow;

// When the app is ready, create window and attempt table connection
app.on('ready', () => {
    try{
        // Create window for gui - will not show until connection is successfully established.
        createWindow();
        // Connect to the table
        connectTable();
    }catch(e){
        // Catch connection error
        console.log(e);
    }
});

// Event for connection
events.on("connect", async () => {
    // notify connected, set bool. 
    console.log("Connected.");
    connected = true;

    // show the gui 
    guiWindow.show();

    // while connected, poll for position and velocity.
    while(connected === true){
        await pollPos();
        await pollVel(); 
    } 
});

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// createWindow - Creates the electron window for the HTML. 
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function createWindow () {
    guiWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      show: false,
      titleBarStyle: 'hidden',
      autoHideMenuBar: true,
      width: 400,
      height: 320,
      resizable: false,
      frame: true,
      webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true
      }
    });
  
    guiWindow.loadFile('index.html');
  }

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// connectTable - essentially the main function - while the application is not connected, it repeatedly
//              attemps to connect. 
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
let connectTable = async () => {

    var attemptCount = 0; 
    while(!connected) {
        console.log("Connecting...");
        attemptCount++;
        await sock.connect("tcp://169.254.114.186:1250");
        await new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{setTimeout(resolve,1000);});
        await delay(1500); // wait 1.5s before attempting to connect again. 

        // Throw error after 15 unsuccessful attempts. 
        if(attemptCount > 15){
            throw "\n\n--Max Connection Attempts Exceded--\nPlease check cables and verify rate table is turned on.\nThen restart application.\n";
        }
    }
    
    return;
};

// // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// pollPos - polls table for position
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
let pollPos = async () => {
    let logic = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // Send the command and wait for the response.
            sock.send("PPO").then(async (result) => {
                let [pMSG] = await sock.receive();
                console.log(" position: " + pMSG.toString('utf8'));
                ipcMain.send('updatePos',pMSG.toString('utf8'));
                return resolve(result);
            }, (error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    });
    return logic;
};

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// pollVel - polls table for velocity
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
let pollVel = async () => {
    let logic = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // Send the command and wait for the response.
            sock.send("PVE").then(async (result) => {
                let [vMSG] = await sock.receive();
                console.log(" velocity: " + vMSG.toString('utf8'));
                ipcMain.send('updateVel',vMSG.toString('utf8'));
                return resolve(result);
            }, (error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    });
    return logic;
};
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script>
    const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

    ipcRenderer.on('updatePos', (event, message) => {
        document.getElementById('pField').innerHTML = message
    });
    ipcRenderer.on('updateVel', (event, message) => {
        document.getElementById('vField').innerHTML = message
    });
</script>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Position/Velocity GUI</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" />
</head>
<style>
    input[type=text]{
        width: 60%;
        border: 2px solid #aaa;
        border-radius: 4px;
        margin: 8px 0;
        outline: none;
        padding: 15px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-size: 18px;
        text-align: right;
    }
</style>
<body style="background: white;">
    <p>
        <h2>Position:</h2>
        <input type="text" id="pField" placeholder="0.000" readonly>
        <h2>Velocity:</h2>
        <input type="text" id="vField" placeholder="0.000" readonly>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change:

```js
ipcMain.send('updatePos',pMSG.toString('utf8'));
ipcMain.send('updateVel',vMSG.toString('utf8'));
```

To:

```
guiWindow.webContents.send('updatePos',pMSG.toString('utf8'));
guiWindow.webContents.send('updateVel',vMSG.toString('utf8'));
```

As far as I know the IPC should be able to handle the rapid requests so give it a shot and see how it turns out.

[See docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main#sending-messages):

> It is also possible to send messages from the main process to the renderer process, see [webContents.send](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentssendchannel-args) for more information.